# JIRA-Eclipse Integration, steps to integrate jira with eclipse-oepe-indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to integrate JIRA with Eclipse(oepe)-Indigo through Eclipse Marketplace but unable to do this.
For this I am trying to install "Atlassian Connector for Eclipse" and getting below message while installing.:

```
"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Atlassian Connector for Eclipse (Required) 3.0.6.v20120628 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.feature.group 3.0.6.v20120628)
  Missing requirement: Atlassian Connector for Eclipse Bamboo UI 3.0.6.v20120628 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.bamboo.ui 3.0.6.v20120628) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench [3.2.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Atlassian Bamboo Integration 3.0.6.v20120628 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.bamboo.feature.group 3.0.6.v20120628)
    To: com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.bamboo.ui [3.0.6.v20120628]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Atlassian Connector for Eclipse (Required) 3.0.6.v20120628 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.feature.group 3.0.6.v20120628)
    To: com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.bamboo.feature.group [3.0.6.v20120628]"
```

Can anyone help me out to do this activity and guide me what should I do for this? Am I missing something which is required?

Comment: Try posting at https://answers.atlassian.com/ , where Atlassian developers and support team could help you too.

Comment: Looks like OP did: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/69603/jira-eclipse-integration-steps-to-integrate-jira-with-eclipse-oepe-indigo

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing the Atlassian Connector through the proper update site on https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Installing+the+Eclipse+Connector#InstallingtheEclipseConnector-EclipseUpdateSites

Answer (score 1):

i am able now to ***integrate JIRA with eclipse-oepe-indigo***. actually, there is a bug in eclipse due to which i was facing problems while doing this activity.

**SYMPTOMS**:-
During installation you may receive an error message similar to one of these:

•Cannot complete the request. See the details.
Cannot find a solution satisfying the following requirements Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.swt/[3.4.0.v3448f,3.4.0.v3448f]].

•Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.swt/[3.4.1.v3449c,3.4.1.v3449c! and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.swt/[3.4.0.v3448f,3.4.0.v3448f! can be satisfied.
Unsatisfied dependency: [org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.soap 3.1.0.I20090109-0100-e3x] requiredCapability: osgi.bundle/org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net/[3.1.0,4.0.0)

•Cannot complete the request. See the details.
Cannot find a solution satisfying the following requirements org.eclipse.pde.feature.jar [3.4.0.v20080603-7T7U-E_EkMNrNKb39WcMC].

•Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Atlassian Connector for Eclipse (recommended) 1.1.0.v20090624 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.feature.group 1.1.0.v20090624)
Missing requirement: Atlassian Connector for Eclipse (recommended) 1.1.0.v20090624 (com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.feature.group 1.1.0.v20090624) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.jira_feature.feature.group [3.2.0.I20090529,3.3.0)' but it could not be found

**CAUSE**:-
This is most likely an error from P2 (Eclipse's update mechanism in Eclipse 3.4 and higher). The problem seems to be that the Mylyn update site is not enabled in your copy of Eclipse. There is a bug in Eclipse that these sites may not be automatically enabled even though we specify that we require them for installation.

If any of the installed features have unsatisfied dependencies or if features were previously installed from the extras or incubator update site, P2 may fail with an error similar to the one above in question

**RESOLUTION**:-
Follow these steps to enable the required sites:

1.In Eclipse, open 'Help', 'Software Updates'.

2.Click the 'Available Software' tab.

3.Click 'Manage Sites'.

4.Look for either the 'Mylyn Extras' update site or a URL that looks like this:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/extras

5.Make sure that the site or URL is checked.

6.Look for either the 'Mylyn For Eclipse 3.4' update site or a URL that looks like this:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4

7.Make sure that the site or URL is checked.

8.Now you should update all installed features to the latest version. Click the 'Installed Software' tab.

9.Click 'Update'.

10.Restart if prompted.

11.Try to install the Atlassian Connector for Eclipse again.